# How to loop input from file and store into array variables?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, loops, input

I am new to C++ and trying learn so pardon me for any mistakes I make. I have a file and within the file it contains data in the following format,

"String" , "String", Character and Number with 100 entries.
 Ie "Billy Joel A 96 Tim McCan B 70".

I want to store theses entries in a array of classes ( maybe I mean instances, or objects, I am new to this so not sure).

This is my bad attempt: 
**the reason why it is bad it does not get the next set of student info... How would I come up with a loop to handle this? So I can get all the students names? There has to be away not to make 100 variables to input things infile.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


class Student{
private:
    int grade;
    char grade_letter; 
public: 
    struct Student_info(){
        void set_firstname();
        void set_lastname(); 
        string get_firstname(); 
        string get_lastname();          
    };


}myStudent_info;

 /// Set / get code below but left out. 

int main()
{ 
    Student myStudent[100];

    ifstream myfile("input.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        string a, b;
        char c;
        int d;

        myfile >> a >> b >> c >> d; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            myStudent[i].myStudentInfo.set_firstname(a);
            myStudent[i].myStudentInfo.set_lastname(b);
            /// the rest of variables...etc                     
        }

        myfile.close();
    }
    //Exit 
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create an array of `Student myStudent[100]` to store the information.

Comment: `myfile >> a >> b << c << d; ` I assume the `<<` before the `c` and `d` is a typo.

Comment: `Student myStudent;` should be `Student myStudent[100];`

Comment: Does your file always have exactly 100 students?

Comment: Sorry both of those are typos, I am not sure how to edit this post once I post it.

Comment: as a sidenote, if your `Student` class is only meant to hold data (as it appears) there is no point in making getter and setter functions. They just make you type more. You could as well make the members public

Comment: There is an edit button under the tags next to share or use this: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38152242/edit

Answer (score 3):

You only input the data of 1 student then loop 100 times. If you want to input the data of 100 students and store each one this is what you should do

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    myfile >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    myStudent[i].myStudentInfo.set_firstname(a);
    myStudent[i].myStudentInfo.set_lastname(b);
    /// the rest of variables...etc                     
}
```

instead of

```
myfile >> a >> b << c << d; 
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    myStudent[i].myStudentInfo.set_firstname(a);
    myStudent[i].myStudentInfo.set_lastname(b);
    /// the rest of variables...etc                     
}
```

Comment: Maybe I messed up but I tried to do that. and it assigned all the 100 the same student name vs different ones in the text file.

Comment: Put `Student myStudent[100];` instead of `Student myStudent;` as @drescherjm said

Answer (score 0):

your on the right track heres my idea of what i would do. but the main point is you need to make a vector or array of students in main.

```
class Student{
private:
  int grade;
  char grade_letter;
  string firstname;
  string lastname;
public: 
      Studnet();
      void set_firstname(string x);
      void set_lastname(string x); 
      void set_letter(char x); 
      void set_grade(int x);          
};


int main() { 
    Student x;
    std::vector<Student> list(100);

    sting input;

    ifstream myfile("input.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while( getline(myfile, input)) {

            // divide input variable into parts
            // use set functions to set student x's values
            // push student x into vector of students list using "list.push_back(x);"

        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The sample input data did not have newlines.